# ITP 2.0 and First Party tracking solution on affiliate networks

Tags: iphone, safari, tracking, affiliate

After the annocement of Apple for ITP 2.0, there are many information from the biggest affiliate networks how to solve the problem. One of the solutions is the First Party tracking solution. 
Can anyone explain how it works? What should the advertiser/publisher do?

Here an example:
https://www.tradedoubler.com/en/global-blog/itp-2-readiness/